# ios MPMoviePlayerController force landscape fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to force the video full screen to be only on landscape, i have tried this. But it does not work.The rest of the app has only portrait.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
Second, Add the method and property

- (void) moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    self.allowRotation = YES;
}
- (void) moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    self.allowRotation = NO;
}
Third, override the supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow method, you can return whatever orientation you want

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (self.allowRotation) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `<MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>` and to add property `allowRotation` and methods `-(void)moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification` and
`-(void)moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification` in AppDelegate.h.